# Sorting of primefaces dataTable with p:columns and converter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a primefaces data table with dynamic colums:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{curSearch.getSearchResults()}"  var="curSearchResult" sortMode="multiple" rowKey="#{curSearchResult.getUniqueId()}">
    <p:columns value="#{curSearch.determinePrimaryPropertyNames()}" var="curPrimaryPropName" sortBy="#{curSearchResult[curPrimaryPropName].getValue()}">
        ...
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

In most cases the value of `sortBy` expressions fits (e. g. for a date or a string), but I have one special data type which must be translated. This means `sortBy="#{curSearchResult[curPrimaryPropName].getValue()}"` delivers a string which must be converted in a i18n string. This i18n string should be sorted then. Unfortunately the attribute `sortBy` throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsExcpetion` if the expression does not contain brackets `[]`. My idea was to call a method and distinguish there between the "normal" values and the values which must be translated. So my 2nd idea is to define a converter for the value which has to be translated. But is converted value evaluated by primefaces? I guess not. Is there maybe another approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like the following code snippet in a Lazy Loading data table and it's working fine.

```
<p:columns value="#{listController.ColumnModel}" 
      width="#{column.width}" var="column" field="#{column.field.fieldName}"   sortBy="#{ticket[column.field.fieldName]}"  
    columnIndexVar="colIndex">
```

I'm storing the field name in the column model as you can see. In the backing bean method used for loading table data  you will receive a list of sortmeta so you can sort your result set. I hope this can help you.

Comment: This does not fit my question. Image that `#{ticket[column.field.fieldName]}` would not be the value you want to sort, instead you pass this value to a method which delivers the translated (i18n) value. How could this be done?

Comment: `curSearchResult` implements the `Map` interface by the way.